# Using Composer's Autoload

Tags: php, autoload, composer-php

I have been looking around the net with no luck on this issue. I am using composer's autoload with this code in my `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"AppName": "src/"}
}
```

But I need to autoload at a higher level than the vendor folder.

Doing something like this does not work:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"AppName": "../src/"}
}
```

Does anyone know a fix or how I can do this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Every package should be responsible for autoloading itself, what are you trying to achieve with autoloading classes that are out of the package you define?

One workaround if it's for your application itself is to add a namespace to the loader instance, something like this:

```
<?php

$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('AppName', __DIR__.'/../src/');
```

Comment: This can be useful for autoloading classes in a test suite, but the actual solution for @chris-r issue is to run "composer.phar update".

Comment: Thank you so much this is work for after two hours searching i found this solution thank you so so so much dear

Comment: Please, consider also that the function ```$loader->add()``` only loads using PSR-0. For load as PSR-4, use ```$loader->addPsr4()``` instead.

Comment: @alexndreazevedo Thanks. I was tearing my hair out for half an hour since my project followed PSR-4 and it wasn't loading properly using `add()`. I've submitted an update to the answer above to mention the proper `addPsr4()` method instead.

Answer (score 55):

The [composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) states that:

> After adding the autoload field, you have to re-run install to
>   re-generate the vendor/autoload.php file.

Assuming your "src" dir resides at the same level as "vendor" dir:

- src

  - AppName
- vendor
- composer.json

the following config is absolutely correct:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"AppName": "src/"}
    }
}
```

but you must re-update/install dependencies to make it work for you, i.e. run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

This command will get the latest versions of the dependencies and update the file "vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php" to match your configuration.

Also as noted by @Dom, you can use `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader without having to go through an update.

Comment: don't you just need to run `composer dump-autoload'?

Comment: @Dom thanks for the hint, I added dump-autoload to my answer.

Answer (score 27):

There also other ways to use the composer autoload features. Ways that can be useful to load packages without namespaces or packages that come with a custom autoload function.

For example if you want to include a single file that contains an autoload function as well you can use the "files" directive as follows:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/",
        "SymfonyStandard": "app/"
    },
    "files": ["vendor/wordnik/wordnik-php/wordnik/Swagger.php"]
},
```

And inside the `Swagger.php` file we got:

```
function swagger_autoloader($className) {
    $currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    if (file_exists($currentDir . '/' . $className . '.php')) {
        include $currentDir . '/' . $className . '.php';
    } elseif (file_exists($currentDir . '/models/' . $className . '.php')) {
        include $currentDir . '/models/' . $className . '.php';
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('swagger_autoloader');
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Otherwise you may want to use a classmap reference:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/", "lib/", "Something.php"]
    }
}
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap

**Note:** during your tests remember to launch the composer `dump-autoload` command or you won't see any change!

```
./composer.phar dump-autoload
```

Happy autoloading =)

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, [Sergiy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15357306/2273611) answer should be the selected answer for the given question. I'm sharing my understanding.

I was looking to autoload my package files using composer which I have under the dir structure given below.

```
<web-root>
    |--------src/
    |           |--------App/
    |           |
    |           |--------Test/
    |
    |---------library/
    |
    |---------vendor/
    |           |
    |           |---------composer/
    |           |           |---------autoload_psr4.php
    |           |           
    |           |----------autoload.php
    |
    |-----------composer.json
    |
```

I'm using [psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoloading specification.

Had to add below lines to the project's composer.json. I intend to place my class files inside src/App , src/Test and library directory.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "OrgName\\AppType\\AppName\\": ["src/App", "src/Test", "library/"]
        }
    }
```

This is pretty much self explaining. *OrgName\AppType\AppName* is my intended namespace prefix.
e.g for class User in ***src/App/Controller/Provider/User.php*** -

```
namespace OrgName\AppType\AppName\Controller\Provider; // namespace declaration

use OrgName\AppType\AppName\Controller\Provider\User; // when using the class
```

Also notice "src/App", "src/Test" .. are from your web-root that is where your composer.json is.
Nothing to do with the vendor dir. take a look at vendor/autoload.php

Now if composer is installed properly all that is required is
**#composer update**

After composer update my classes loaded successfully.
What I observed is that composer is adding a line in vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
    'OrgName\\AppType\\AppName\\' => array($baseDir . '/src/App', $baseDir . '/src/Test', $baseDir . '/library'),
);
```

This is how composer maps.
For psr-0 mapping is in vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php

Answer (score 3):

Just create a symlink in your src folder for the namespace pointing to the folder containing your classes...

```
ln -s ../src/AppName ./src/AppName
```

Your autoload in composer will look the same...

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"AppName": "src/"}
}
```

And your AppName namespaced classes will start a directory up from your current working directory in a `src` folder now... that should work.

Comment: Hello !
Thank you, you're the only one I found with my configuration, maybe you could help me :)
I also created a symlink, but when I run `composer update -o` Composer don't understand the classes folder.

Do you have an idea ? Please ..

Answer (score 3):

The autoload config does start below the vendor dir. So you might want change the vendor dir, e.g.

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "../vendor/"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"AppName": "src/"}
    }
}
```

Or isn't this possible in your project?

Comment: Incorrect; `src/` is relative to the project root, not `vendor`.  See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading .