# PHP Slim framework: autoload

Tags: php, autoload, slim

I use the Slim framework, and I wish I could properly handle self loading files.
At the moment I have this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $list = array(
        dirname(__DIR__).'/app/'.$class.'.php',
        dirname(__DIR__).'/lib/'.$class.'.php',
        dirname(__DIR__).'/lib/'.$class.'.class.php',
    );
    foreach($list as $k => $v){if(file_exists($v)){
        include $v; return true;
    }}
});
```

And this structure:

```
lib\
    Function.php
    MyNamespace\
        Class.php
vendor\
    slim\
web\
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Is it the best method to autoload Slim without using Composer? (in the case you can't install Composer on your server or you don't want to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim can use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to autoload classes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload) more info about using it.

Also the `return true;` statement in the foreach loop would end the functions execution, without having the whole `$list` array iterated.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that answer, but now if I do not want used loader Composer, is there a solution for slim?