# session_start() in Session class constructor (multiple session starts on every url or not)

Tags: php, session-cookies

- session_start() method is in Session.php class constructor
- Session.php class is required in every page header 
  (require_once('Session.php'))

That means that Session class will be included again when I redirect to another url and every time new session will be started. This will cause errors.

But this piece of code works properly, why?

```
class Session {
    private $signed_in = false;
    public $user_id;
    private $is_admin;
    public $message;
    public $count;

    function __construct() {

        session_start();
        $this->visitor_count();
        $this->check_the_login();
        $this->check_message();
    }

} //End of Session Class

$session = new Session();
```

Why I should start new session on every initialization of Session class

Comment: [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) does not always start a new session, it also resumes an existing one (first sentence of the doc)

Comment: You cannot call `session_start()` twice in the same script. Two URL requests are two different script executions.

Comment: Okay then it's not bad idea to have session_start() on every page?

Comment: It is _necessary_ to have it on every page, otherwise it won’t work correctly to begin with.

Comment: u can also create a file like autoload and use session in this file, something like CI framework. are u using any framework here?

Comment: PHP is interpreted, every time that a user request a page, its a new "start/end" process. You need remember php thats has a session, at least, in one of pages processed.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is call session_start in the middle of the code:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

> Note:
>
> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

Try put it at start of file, before class declaration, or in a another include.

Comment: My piece of code is working properly, I just wanted to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I would decouple your session class from the `session_start` command (sounds silly but bear with) to avoid the posiblity of the calls to it becoming confused and/or forgotton and/or called at the wrong time (after headers).

If you are not using a framework, which I can assume youre not as youre dealing with sessions directly, then I would probably opt for putting the `session_start` call in a custom autoloader file which you load at the start of each request.

Something like this (assumes your'e using composer's autolaoder)

**custom_autoload.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $loader = require __DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

This way you know its called before any output to the browser.  Then your session class can be responsible for handling the contents of `$_SESSION` which should be its single job.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload) question and answers for good guidance on using composers autoloader if your'e not familiar with it.