# Why the "use" command in PHP not working with include?

Tags: php

I have this script:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Church\Config;
use Church\SQLiteConnection;
use Church\Template;
use Church\User;
$ERROR = "";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['username']))
{
  $login = new User((new SQLiteConnection())->connect());
  if($login->loginUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
  {

  }
  else {
    $ERROR = "login";
  }
}

if(isset($_GET['go']))
{

}
else {
  if (!file_exists(Config::PATH_TO_SQLITE_FILE)) {
    include('init/install.php');
  }
}
```

When I make it with this part:

```
include('init/install.php');
```

instead of this:

```
$tpl = new Template('templates/install.tpl');
$tpl->set('HEADER', $tpl->getFile('templates/header.tpl'));
$tpl->set('FOOTER', $tpl->getFile('templates/footer.tpl'));
$tpl->set('APP_NAME', Config::APP_NAME);
$tpl->set('APP_VERSION', Config::APP_VERSION);
$tpl->set('BASE_URL', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$tpl->render();
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Template' not found in
```

I do not understand why it is working without include but with include is the auto loading not working. What did I miss?

Comment: You should probably get familiar how [composer autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload) works.

Comment: [This could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25138965/3536236)

Comment: If you want to use Composer autoload you need to comply with [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) naming conventions. Otherwise, you need to write your own auto-loader (although you can try and plug it into Composer, but you need to configure it properly).

Comment: The OP has not mentioned or referenced composer. Why is everyone going on about it?

Comment: @codedge thanks I could fix is with your hint.

Comment: How does that file in question look like? Is it probably missing the `use` statements?

Comment: @Martin We've all assumed it from the `vendor/autoload.php` include and lack of any other reference to class loading.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. **This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime**, so it cannot be block scoped. The following example will show an illegal use of the use keyword:

And then:

> **Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.**

The conclusion is that you can't do what you want to do. You need to import (aka *use*) in your included file too.