# My __autoload function doesn't work after installing JSON web token and composer

Tags: php, jwt

So i have an mvc php project and i have a core.php that has an __autoload function that loads my controller and model classes like this:

```
 <?php
 function __autoload($classname) {
  if (strhas($classname, "Model")) {
    $filename = str_replace("Model", "", $classname);
    $filename = strtolower($filename);
    require_once("mvc/model/$filename.php");
    return;
  }

  if (strhas($classname, "Controller")) {
    $filename = str_replace("Controller", "", $classname);
    $filename = strtolower($filename);
    require_once("mvc/controller/$filename.php");
    return;
  }
}
```

but after installing JSON web token (JWT) and composer my __autoload function no longer works and my controllers are no longer found.

this is my project structure:

```
index.php
system/
 -core.php
 -loader.php
 -...
mvc/
 -controller/
  --...
 -model/
  --...
...
```

Comment: May be worth looking at how to use the autoloading within compose - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's precisely the drawback of `__autoload()` and the reason for this remarks [in the manual](http://That's%20the%20drawback%20of%20%60__autoload()%60%20and%20the%20reason%20for%20the%20[notes%20in%20the%20manual):

> The [spl_autoload_register()](https://php.net/spl_autoload_register) function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a last chance to load the class or interface before it fails with an error.
>
> **Tip** Although the `__autoload()` function can also be used for autoloading classes and interfaces, it's preferred to use the [spl_autoload_register()](https://php.net/spl_autoload_register) function. This is because it is a more flexible alternative (enabling for any number of autoloaders to be specified in the application, such as in third party libraries). For this reason, using `__autoload()` is discouraged and deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0.

You can either use the recommended replacement or [configure Compose to load your own custom classes](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) (your schema looks similar to PSR-4 so it should work with minor changes).